# Bash double and single quotes, i cant solve this

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash script. In a curl command I need a variable... It's just never recognized, or the command doesn't work. I searched the forum but didn't find anything suitable. Can you help me?

```
message="test"
curl -XPOST -d '{"msgtype":"m.text", "body":"$message"}' $curlurl
```

Since I need this json format, the double quotes must remain.

Thank you.
Greetz Daniel

I have tried:

Substitute Single quote to double quote... \ to lose its meaning... but nothing work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434290/jq-bash-make-json-array-from-variable

Comment: In evaluating answers on the linked duplicates, the ones that use `jq --arg var "$var"` are categorically better (more reliable, more secure) than ones that don't. An answer that doesn't use jq will let a message's text exit the quotes it's contained in and insert extra fields into the message being posted, or simply be invalid and fail to be accepted by the server; using jq correctly will _always_ result in well-formed output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$message` appears in a single-quoted string, so is not expanded. (The `"` are just parts of that single-quoted string, and have nothing to do with shell quoting.)

The "correct" version would be to double-quote the string and escape the embedded quotes:

```
curl -XPOST -d "{\"msgtype\":\"m.text\", \"body\":\"$message\"}' "$curlurl"
```

but this is both tedius and fragile, as you need to ensure any double quotes in the value of `message` are properly escaped. Much simpler is to let a tool like `jq` generate your JSON for you.

```
jq --arg m "$message" '{msgtype: "m.text", body: $m}' |
   curl -XPOST -d @-
```

`@-` tells the `-d` option to read from standard input.